# Global variable value issue iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have declared a variable  NSString sessionId; in app delegate file for global usage.

In appdelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *sessionId;
```

In appdelegate.m

```
@synthesize sessionId;
```

And used it in one of my view controller like this.

```
    ((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID.retain;

NSLog(@"session id = %@", ((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId);
```

I am able to accèss that variable sessionId in all of my view controllers but the issue is that the value is not getting saved in it. Like in viewcontroller1.m, I assigned it some value but when I accessed sessionId in another viewcontroller2.m, its showing its value as null on console.

How can I resolve this issue.

Code added:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

self.receivedData = nil;


    NSError *error;

    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSArray *session = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];

    SBJsonParser *parser =[[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:responseString];

    sID = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"session"];

    ((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID;

    NSLog(@"session id = %@", ((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId);


    NSUserDefaults *sessID = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [sessID setObject:sID forKey:@"sessionID"];

    [sessID synchronize];

    NSLog(@"This session %@ saved", sID);

    NSDictionary *accountsObj = [parser objectWithString:responseString];

    NSString *accounts = [accountsObj objectForKey:@"account"];

    NSArray *accountList = [accounts componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"Accounts: %@", accountList);


    if (session == nil)
    NSLog(@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
else {

    if (accountList.count > 1) {

        ChooseAccountsController *accountsView = [[ChooseAccountsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseAccountsController" bundle:nil ];

        self.chooseAcc = accountsView;

        [self.view addSubview: accountsView.view];
    } else if (accountList.count == 1) {

            MainScreenController *mainScreen1 = [[MainScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil ];

             self.mainScreen = mainScreen1;

             [self.view addSubview: mainScreen1.view];

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, show us how you did declare the variable in the first place, please.

Comment: man, your variable naming is horrible! why do you assign your user defaults to an name sessID?

Comment: before getting into application delegate variable stuff, I was thinking of nsuserdefaults to save the sessionId, thats y

Comment: I don't see, why you need this property on your AppDelegate. Just write and read it to/from your `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` where needed.

Comment: was just gonna try it... but didn't used it... now I have deleted it .. if the solution you have suggested will work fine then I don't need another method ... but still I am getting issue of variable values getting null sometimes and sometimes not ... this abnormal behavior is very bad ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID.retain;
```

is not valid code, try

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID
```

a strong property should be retaining, and also retain is a message, so if you need this (not in this case) the only correct syntax is `[anObject retain]`

try

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"session"];
```

Comment: I have tried that code too, still it is not showing the value

Comment: Then you have an issue when sID is created, show us that code.

Comment: Hey I have got something on console which is while leaving the viewcontroller1, sessionId is setting up to null. Why is it happening? How can I retain the value

Comment: you don't have to retain it, as your setter, that you synthesize, takes care of it.

Comment: Edited my code. If that is not working, than either your jsonObject does not exist, or no object for the key session in it.

Comment: hey @vikingosegundo thanx dude your code has worked :) thanx again you have solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Honestly dont know why this not work, but try to create a Singleton Object to save and Access this Variable. This is more elegant and should serve your Intent.

Comment: @DennsS. you are right to recommend using another singleton instead of cluttering the appDelegate with such stuff for style reasons. That however will not solve the issue the OP has. Its only a question of good style.

Comment: I think in this case the best suggestion is to use the standard users default — yet another singleton

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID.retain;
```

should read

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).sessionId = sID;
```

I wonder that it worked at all without crashing...

Comment: He is using arc — hence the strong property

Comment: Well according to the doc's, strong simply translates to retain when ARC is disabled - so you never know until explicitly stated ;-)

Comment: and yet his property is retaining anyway, so your code would overretain

Answer (score 0):

NSLog its value in viewcontroller1 to make sure its set.

If it is, then it is most likely that in viewcontroller2 you are redefining the sessionid when you try to access it.

Also you may want to create a singleton outside of the AppDelegate.

Comment: yes in viewcontroller1 it shows the result two times on console, once it shows the value which is assigned and in second result it shows it as null ... I'm not getting this behavior